# Create wordpress subpages navigation with some options

Tags: wordpress

I need some help with wordpress.
The idea is create multioptional navigation in sidebar.
Hierarchy is looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>First Page
    <ul>
    <li>First SubPage</li>
    <li>Second SubPage
        <ul>
        <li>First Sub-SubPage</li>
        <li>Second Sub-SubPage</li>
        <li>Third Sub-SubPage</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Second Page</li>
<li>Third Page
    <ul>
    <li>First SubPage</li>
    <li>Second SubPage
        <ul>
        <li>First Sub-SubPage</li>
        <li>Second Sub-SubPage</li>
        <li>Third Sub-SubPage</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

But i need some features.
When i on First Page, i want see only subpages of this page, not all pages in menu.

How i can resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the function `get_pages` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

You can use the following function. Call it in the sidebar with `$page_id as <current page id>`.

```
<?php    
function show_child_list($page_id) {
    $child_pages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $page_id, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'ASC', 'parent' => $page_id) );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($child_pages as $child) {
        echo '<li>'.$child->post_title.'</li>';
        show_child_list($child->ID);
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Update 1:

Added `'parent' => $page_id` attribute in third line, so only first level child are returned.

Comment: Thanks for help. but isn't help me, i get all the tree of wordpress.

Comment: Then I guess you are not calling the function with current page id.(Updated code to avoid child items showing multiple times.)

Comment: i try to solve it via css, display:none. i think its another way. because i have 4 level menu. it's so complex.

Comment: yep, now it's looks good, but i think CSS way is better :)
thank you very much :)